# Writing out the category of a product from Duka Press Plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I'm trying to modify a wordpress plugin called Duka Press, and I'm a complete noobie to PHP. It uses shortcodes which produces the template for the product grid, and I basically just need to write out all the categories the product has to create jQuery filter function.

To better understand what I need read the HTML comment in the code underneath

CODE:

```
     <ul>
        I need this for each category inside the active category set i the shortcode:
        <li>[CategoryNameHere]</li>
     </ul>

$products = get_posts($order_string . 'numberposts=' . $per_page . '&post_type=' . $type . '&meta_key=price&category=' . $category . $offset);
if (is_array($products) && count($products) > 0) {
    $content .= '<div class="dpsc_grid_display">';
    $count = 1;
    $all_count = 0;
    foreach ($products as $product) {
        $output = dpsc_get_product_details($product->ID, $p_b_n, $direct_checkout);
        if ($output) {
            $attachment_images = &get_children('post_type=attachment&post_status=inherit&post_mime_type=image&post_parent=' . $product->ID);
            $main_image = '';
            foreach ($attachment_images as $image) {
                $main_image = $image->guid;
                break;
            }
            $prod_permalink = get_permalink($product->ID);
            $content .= '<div class="dpsc_grid_product">';
            $content .= '<div class="dpsc_grid_product_image">';
            if ($main_image != '') {
                $content .= '<a href="' . $prod_permalink . '" title="' . $product->post_title . '"><img src="' . DP_PLUGIN_URL . '/lib/timthumb.php?src=' . $main_image . '&w=' . $dp_shopping_cart_settings['g_w'] . '&h=' . $dp_shopping_cart_settings['g_h'] . '&zc=1" ></a>';
            }
            $content .= '</div>';

            <!-- In the following line i need to write out all the categories for the current product -->
            $content .= '<div class="dpsc_grid_product_detail [Categories here]">';

            $content .= '<p class="title"><a href="' . $prod_permalink . '" title="' . $product->post_title . '">' . __($product->post_title) . '</a></p>';                
            $content .= '<p class="detail">' . $product->post_excerpt . '</p>';
            $content .= '<p class="price">' . $output['price'] . '</p>';
            $content .= $output['start'];
            $content .= $output['add_to_cart'];
            $content .= $output['end'];
            $content .= '</div>';
            $content .= '</div>';
            if ($count === intval($column)) {
                $content .= '<div class="clear"></div>';
                $count = 0;
            }
            $count++;
            $all_count++;
        }
    }
    $content .= '<div class="clear"></div>' . $page_links . '<div class="clear"></div>';
    $content .= '</div>';
    $content .= '<div class="clear"></div>';
}
return $content;
```

Shortcode that uses the template above: 
[dpsc_grid_display category="22" total="100" column="3" per_page="100" type="duka"]